# Default Package Sizes of React Native and NativeScript

Tags: react-native, size, apk, nativescript, ipa

I have read several articles taking a qualitative approach to the package size of `React Native` and `NativeScript`. The general consensus seems to be that `React Native` is produces a "light weight" product and `NativeScript` causes a "heavy" product.

Do numerical metrics (in megabytes) exist on this topic? Such as minimum IPA / APK size for each platform on iOS and Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with React-Native default template and its IPA & APK size but when talking about **NativeScript** you should consider the following:

- by default when creating and building your first application, this happens in debug mode without any performance or/and size optimizations.
- To improve both the performance and the size of your generated package you can use [bundling with webpack](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/bundling-with-webpack). The normal workflow would be to create your application in debug using the CLI (e.g. `tns create myApp --tsc`) and then when you are ready to test the app for production to install WebPack and bundle the project.

Furthermore, you have the option to build only for specific architectures using ABI Splits.